# Elasticsearch - Bootstrap checks failing

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use the Flink 5.x Elasticsearch sink connector to insert data to ES 5.2.1 instance hosted on a tiny VM.

As this is a tiny VM in development mode, I cant get it to start up to accept TransportClient remote client connections on 9300 without failing the bootstrap checks.

```
[2017-02-17T09:02:48,581][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [Z_fiBnl] starting ...
[2017-02-17T09:02:48,866][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [Z_fiBnl] publish_address {xxxxxx:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}
[2017-02-17T09:02:48,878][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [Z_fiBnl] bound or publishing to a non-loopback or non-link-local address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: bootstrap checks failed
max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
max number of threads [1024] for user [xxx] is too low, increase to at least [2048]
max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk
```

I've played around with the below settings but just cant get it to startup(http clients on 9200 work fine)

```
transport.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
transport.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
http.host: "xxx"
http.host: 169.117.72.167
network.host: 0.0.0.0
network.publish_host: 0.0.0.0
```

Note that ES is running on a tiny VM just for dev purposes and I don't have access to change for ex. the file descriptor limits on this box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this by using the below setting available since ES 5.2
 discovery.type: single-node
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html)

Once I brought up the ES node with that setting, I was able to connect using the transport client from a non localhost client which was a problem before.

Comment: it seems like this works only since ES 5.4
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/25525

Answer (score 38):

> max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low,
>   increase to at least [65536]

```
ulimit -n 65536
```

or set `nofile` to `65536` in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

> max number of threads [1024] for user [xxx] is too low, increase to at
>   least [2048]

```
ulimit -u 2048
```

Or set the `nproc` value to `2048` or above in `/etc/security/limits.conf` before starting elasticsearch.

> max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase
>   to at least [262144]

set `vm.max_map_count=262144` in `/etc/sysctl.conf`
then do `sysctl -p`

**If you want to run elasticsearch in development environment despite failing bootstrap checks:**

Set the following in your `elasticsearch.yml`

```
transport.host: 127.0.0.1
http.host: 0.0.0.0
```

Please note you cant form a cluster in development mode. **Dont use elasticsearch that is failing bootstrap checks in production!!**

Comment: Thanks but I dont have permissions on the Unix host to alter the ulimit for ex. Is there a way to set dev mode so that the bootstrap checks dont get called and the transport client service binds to the public network interface ?

Comment: I understand about the production mode, i'm just trying to set up a remote ES process on Linux and then use an Windows based IDE to develop a TransportClient service based cllient ? Looks like I cant do that because of the bootstrap checks limiting the pubish host to only local IPs ?

Comment: Yea, Unfortunately you cant do that in dev mode, Only http endpoint can be exposed in dev.

Comment: @FarhadFarahi the first issue is not resolved. Do we need any extra step on that?

Answer (score 31):

#### Issue is "max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]"

vm.max_map_count is very low, increasing its count will solve the issue

#### 1. Linux

check with the vm.max_map_count setting in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
grep vm.max_map_count /etc/sysctl.conf
```

> OUTPUT : vm.max_map_count=262144

If the output is less than 262144, Apply the new count as elasticsearch expects, we have two options to add permanently or temporary fix.

add the varibale to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
vm.max_map_count=262144
```

OR

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

#### 2. OSX with Docker for Mac

The vm.max_map_count setting must be set within the xhyve virtual machine:

```
screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

Log in with the root and no password. Then configure the sysctl setting as you would for Linux:

```
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

#### 3. OSX with Docker Toolbox

The vm.max_map_count setting must be set via docker-machine:

```
docker-machine ssh

sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

#### 4. Docker Desktop with WSL on Windows

The vm.max_map_count setting must be set via wsl:

```
wsl

sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: Here's the solution if using Minikube on MacOS https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2367

Comment: @AndyCarlson, this is very generic problem with `max_map_count` in elasticsearch. not related to the minikube.

Comment: Yes, I am aware it's not a Minikube bug. Your answer is awesome and I just wanted to provide the solution if anybody encounters this issue inside a Minikube setup. I got this error when trying to run an Elasticsearch container in Minikube, and since the steps to solve it are a little bit different than with Docker Machine or Docker for Mac, I wanted to link this solution to help save others some time.

Answer (score 22):

Try configuring your elasticsearch.yml file this way :

`network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300`

Comment: Thanks, with this setting, i did not have to setup any extra settings like increasing the OS level file descriptors setting which is needed due to bootstrap failures complained on starting elasticsearch

Comment: This has worked like a charm, can you please let us know how and why? I thought these settings should be set by default. Is this production setting? or only in dev? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 9):

I just add

> transport.host: localhost

and it just worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

For **max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]**

1. Check `ulimit -n`, it would be 4096.
2. Edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` and add following lines:

   `*    soft nofile 65536`

   `*    hard nofile 65536`

   `root soft nofile 65536`

   `root hard nofile 65536`
3. Edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session` and add this line `session required pam_limits.so`
4. Edit `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` and add this line `session required pam_limits.so`
5. Reload session and check for `ulimit -n`, it would be 65536.

For **max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]**

1. Run following command `sudo sh -c "echo 'vm.max_map_count=262144' >> /etc/sysctl.conf"`

*References*:

1. https://underyx.me/2015/05/18/raising-the-maximum-number-of-file-descriptors
2. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/vm-max-map-count.html

Comment: how to check for  ulimin -n ? where do I use the check please? on terminal,  or in which file?

Answer (score 3):

Following steps helped us get started with ES 5.5.2. On Azure with 3 master, 3 client and 8 data nodes using Ubuntu servers

1. Ensure following configurations in "/etc/security/limits.conf"

> *soft memlock unlimited
>
> *hard memlock unlimited

2. ulimit -l unlimited
3. ulimit -n 65536
4. sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
5. Make sure that elasticsearch.yml has following configurations parameter

> transport.tcp.compress: true
>
> transport.tcp.port: 9300

**Note** We also had to stop "apparmor" service to fix connectivity issue between nodes.

Answer (score 2):

```
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed. You must address the points described in the following [1] lines before starting Elasticsearch.
In 2023:If you are getting this error then follow these steps
```

**firstly---> If you are using docker images,Follow these commands**

- for elastic

  sudo docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.1
- for kibana

  sudo docker pull docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.6.1

8.6.1: Pulling from kibana/kibana

- create network

  sudo docker network create elastic
- inspect to check if everything is good

  sudo docker inspect elastic
- check all your docker images

  sudo docker images
- make sure to use full name like 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 ....

  sudo docker run --name es01-test --net elastic -p 127.0.0.1:9200:9200 -p 127.0.0.1:9300:9300 -e "discovery.type=single-node" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.6.1

***and if your docker container is already in use then make sure to remove it first using***

```
sudo docker rm [container-name]
```

***removing a container will also delete all the data present inside that container***

***and if your docker container is running then make sure to stop it first***

```
sudo docker stop [container-name]
```

***To start***

```
sudo docker start [container-name]
```

- **repeat same for kibana as well**

***open another terminal and repeat the same process***

And to Download kibana and elasticsearch docker latest images visit **docker hub**

And if you are running from the bin folder by (.bat files) and got stuck with something then comment down, I will instantly get back to you

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when running on docker-compose. I'm using macOS Ventura and Apple Silicon.

I got It fixed with:

```
environment:
  - network.host=0.0.0.0
  - http.port=9200
  - transport.host=localhost
  - cluster.name=docker-cluster
  - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
  - xpack.security.enabled=false
  - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m"
```

My final `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.1'
services:

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.0-arm64
    platform: linux/arm64/v8
    container_name: elasticsearch
    environment:
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - http.port=9200
      - transport.host=localhost
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048m -Xms2048m"
    volumes:
      - esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1 

volumes:
  esdata:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score -1):

Been scouring google for this and apply different suggestion, but I think this is the general solution:

check for the actual limit when the process is running (albeit short) with:

```
cat /proc/<pid>/limits
```

You will find lines similar to this:

```
Limit                     Soft Limit           Hard Limit           Units     
Max cpu time              unlimited            unlimited            seconds   
Max file size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max data size             unlimited            unlimited            bytes     
Max stack size            8388608              unlimited            bytes     
Max core file size        0                    unlimited            bytes 
<truncated>
```

Then depend on the runner or container (in my case it was supervisord's minfds value), you can lift the actual limitation configuration.