# Unable to start Elasticsearch：bootstrap checks failed

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

When I run bin/elasticsearch, it throws the following errors:

ERROR: [2] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max file descriptors [8192] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65536]
[2]: system call filters failed to install; check the logs and fix your configuration or disable system call filters at your own risk

To solve error[1], I have done:

```
sudo vim /etc/security/limits.conf
```

and modify:

```
*           soft    nofile          65536
*           hard    nofile          65536
```

Then I re-start Elasticsearch but the error still exists.

Following is the completed /etc/security/limits.conf:

```
# /etc/security/limits.conf
#
#Each line describes a limit for a user in the form:
#<domain>        <type>  <item>  <value>
#Where:
#<domain> can be:
#        - an user name
#        - a group name, with @group syntax
#        - the wildcard *, for default entry
#        - the wildcard %, can be also used with %group syntax,
#                 for maxlogin limit
#<type> can have the two values:
#        - "soft" for enforcing the soft limits
#        - "hard" for enforcing hard limits
#<item> can be one of the following:
#        - core - limits the core file size (KB)
#        - data - max data size (KB)
#        - fsize - maximum filesize (KB)
#        - memlock - max locked-in-memory address space (KB)
#        - nofile - max number of open files
#        - rss - max resident set size (KB)
#        - stack - max stack size (KB)
#        - cpu - max CPU time (MIN)
#        - nproc - max number of processes
#        - as - address space limit
#        - maxlogins - max number of logins for this user
#        - maxsyslogins - max number of logins on the system
#        - priority - the priority to run user process with
#        - locks - max number of file locks the user can hold
#        - sigpending - max number of pending signals
#        - msgqueue - max memory used by POSIX message queues (bytes)
#        - nice - max nice priority allowed to raise to
#        - rtprio - max realtime priority
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>

#*               soft    core            0
#*               hard    rss             10000
#@student        hard    nproc           20
#@faculty        soft    nproc           20
#@faculty        hard    nproc           50
#ftp             hard    nproc           0
#@student        -       maxlogins       4
# End of file

# Oracle-Validated setting for nofile soft limit is 131072
oracle   soft   nofile    131072

# Oracle-Validated setting for nofile hard limit is 131072
oracle   hard   nofile    131072

# Oracle-Validated setting for nproc soft limit is 131072
oracle   soft   nproc    131072

# Oracle-Validated setting for nproc hard limit is 131072
oracle   hard   nproc    131072

# Oracle-Validated setting for core soft limit is unlimited
oracle   soft   core    unlimited

# Oracle-Validated setting for core hard limit is unlimited
oracle   hard   core    unlimited

# Oracle-Validated setting for memlock soft limit is 50000000
oracle   soft   memlock    50000000

# Oracle-Validated setting for memlock hard limit is 50000000
oracle   hard   memlock    50000000

@svrtech    soft    memlock         500000
@svrtech    hard    memlock         500000
*           soft    nofile          65536
*           hard    nofile          65536
```

Any help on this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: above issue is been explained and answered in below thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300463/elasticsearch-5-x-bootstrap-checks-failing

Comment: @sanath Thanks, the problem is fixed!