# max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]

Tags: elasticsearch, unix, sonarqube, ubuntu-18.04

I get this error when starting sonarqube.
I have tried:

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Which returns:

```
sysctl: setting key "vm.max_map_count"
```

And then:

```
sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count
```

It still says

```
vm.max_map_count = 65530
```

Does anyone know why Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't update vm.max_map_count?

[Image with response from server commands](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzElT.png)

Thanks in advace, 
Xander

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300463/elasticsearch-bootstrap-checks-failing#answer-47211716

Comment: @JinnaBalu, I don't think you understand. My vm.max_map_count just doesn't update even after running the commands in the solution you presented. That's why I asked this question!

Comment: It works for the current session on every restart it will reset back. To achieve the persistence /etc/sysctl.conf add the variable and value.

Comment: I have tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The changes have not been applied on system. Run the `sudo sysctl -p` command to apply them and check the value again `sudo sysctl vm.max_map_count`.

Comment: Hey sorry, I didn't mention it but it still doesn't update when I execute that command. I forgot to add that to the question. [image](https://imgur.com/a/5n3U0Pi)

Comment: All right. Tested and worked on Ubuntu 20.04 & Debian 10. Try out again: sudo bash -c  "echo 'vm.max_map_count=262144' >> /etc/sysctl.conf" && sudo sysctl -p

Comment: Hey Alexadreison, `sudo bash -c "echo 'vm.max_map_count=262144' >> /etc/sysctl.conf" && sudo sysctl -p` also doesn't change my vm.max_map_count!
It's really wierd...

Answer (score 0):

running on docker or kubernetes, it is an optional to Elasticsearch bootstrap check be ignored in docker env

```
  containers: 
    - name: sonarqube
      image: sonarqube
      args: 
        - -Dsonar.web.context=/sonar
        - -Dsonar.es.bootstrap.checks.disable=true
```